# How long can poison stay in the cats body?

Tags: cats, death, domestication

***Minni***.

> 05.12.2021

Minni, my favourite pet, who had given birth to adorable kitties few weeks back seemed to be lethargic when I checked her in the morning. Further more look at the backyard suggested some serious problem. She was throwing up some sort of food I had never fed her. When she was uncontrollably vomiting and lying down in pain, a visit to vet, who gave her fluids strongly suspected case of poisoning. He said that he can dilute the poison but cant give surety of her life. A motionless Minni was up and running when we were back home from vet. She was in pain due to injections but was feeling better and was all okay the whole week but only to have a repeat of the previous week again.

This time she was throwing up only bile juice. She ran away from the backyard, was trying to hide. I was unable to find her in spite of searching all around. She returned back, next morning, feebly calling out and not sure why just wanted to keep her legs in water. She refused to eat or drink.
After some time threw up again. Being a Sunday, no vets were available even after calling dozen of clinics. Tried online vet service, was advised to give ORS fluid as she was not much responsive. The poison was still in her body. I don't know how she fell ill again. She was trying to hide away.

When I had lost hope, some vet rang back but by the time I took her there she had already stepped into the other world. She kicked the box couple of times on the way and slowly the breaths had reduced.

It was very hard to believe that A kind, loving Minni was no more. Her meows are still ringing in my ears. I keep my sight at my window, hoping my dear friend will come back and call me again.

She lives on in her adorable kitties who are 8 weeks old now and resemble her all around.

**My questions are.**

1. **How long can poison stay in the cats body?**
2. **How did the poison affect her again? She was all normal active Minni after fluids were given. Why did it relapse?**

*This is my cute little Minni, who gave me a lifetime of memories to cherish*
[image: my lovely friend, minni]

*Adieu my dear friend, will meet again in the heavens someday.*

Comment: My condolences. Passing of a beloved pet is never easy. I hope the best for her litter. They are lucky to have a human companion like you.

Comment: About the poison, she might be all better with the fluid injections but poisoned again next week.

Comment: @C.Koca This thought makes me so devastated. What on earth was the poor feline's fault that some one fed her poison and that too repeatedly :'/

Comment: Even if "poisoned again" hypothesis is true, it doesn't necessitate an intentional poisoning. The cat might expose herself again to some spillage that wasn't cleaned up at the first place. That spillage might not necessarily be fatal, maybe poor Minni was already susceptible because of an underlying condition.

Comment: The surest way would be to do a post mortem. And I would strongly suggest to keep kittens strictly inside for some time.

Comment: @C.Koca yes i have all of them inside. Thanks for concern.

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss. Unfortunately, you've learned the hard way why it's better to keep a pet indoors. The poison could have been a spill, a deliberate act by a malicious neighbor, or an accident (cats who eat poisoned rodents, for instance, will become poisoned in turn) and there's no way of knowing what it could have been from a post like this.

Comment: @Allison C yeah. Hard way. It'll be a mystery forever and I'll be left with ifs and buts. She was a feral cat and took me really long to get her adapted to human touch. Wish God had given her some more time here.

Comment: Take good care of those kittens, and keep them inside where they're safe. That's the best thing to do now, make sure her kittens enjoy the good life she should have had.

Comment: @AllisonC one of the kittens refuses to eat anything. just drinks water and keeps searching for mom. I dont know what to do. Advise

Comment: Please write this as a separate question. I don't have the answer myself but you'll get one much faster that way.

Comment: Okay. I have posted. Hoping for some solution.

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/33178/kitten-refuses-to-eat-after-mama-cats-death-getting-weaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry for the loss of your cat.

> How long can poison stay in the cats body?

It depends on several factors:

- what exact poison is that;
- the "strength" / health / age of the cat;
- is there anything in the cat's food which acts like an antidote for that poison?
- is the cat given any poison-fighting aid? (you  provided to your cat some fluids);
- etc.

Also, please note that the question actually has 2 sides.

1. How much time does it take for the cat to die, after (s)he ingested the poison?
2. How much time is the poison still active in the body of the cat after the cat dies? It matters, in case that another animal will eat the cat's dead body.

> How did the poison affect her again? She was all normal active Minni after fluids were given. Why did it relapse?

Only an autopsy could give some clue on that - possibly not much. Besides the factors mentioned above, another factor is:

- does (did) the cat come in contact with the poison again? (same poison, or different)?