# Kitten diarrhea not stopping. Please advise

Tags: cats, domestication

[How long can poison stay in the cats body?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/33175/how-long-can-poison-stay-in-the-cats-body/33181#33181)

A kitten, who is one of the 3 kittens (other 2 succumbed by starving after mama cat's death) of the cat in the above question is having loose stools.

Vet had advised to give oflokind oz antibiotics but it hasn't worked and the vet is not interested to listen to the kitten's complaints. Even this kitten like the other 2 stopped eating post mama cat's death. However, I started force feeding this one with canned food(which I had never used earlier when it was eating normally) and I observed it is having diarrhea. Vet advised to avoid any food and give curd rice but still the problem persists. I'm currently feeding around 2 ml of rice mixed with curd every 1-2 hours.

1. What else can I try to stop the kitten diarrhea? (it is getting weaker)
2. What can I do to make the kitten eat on its own? (it's been 5 days since it's mama's death and 2 days since its littermates left)

Comment: Can you go to a different vet? Or is that vet the only one in your area?

Comment: With young kittens diarrhea, the immediate concern here is fluid intake, as they dehydrate very quickly. I am not sure what type of curd you are using, however you should make sure it is lactose-free, since lactose can cause (or worsen) diarrhea. Regarding nutrition by age, you can see https://www.catcarecenter.com/services/cats/kitten-care for resources, they also have a short booklet on taking care of orphaned kittens. As for fluid intake, canned food can be mixed in a blender with some fresh water, blended it can go in a syringe to feed in mouth (without needle of course).

Comment: @bgse yea I'm feeding water mixed with glucose too. I'm not able to understand the cause of diarrhea whether its from canned food or curd and what should I give to fill its stomach and energize. And yea he is the only vet in a large area around. What can i do so that it comes out n eat on its own

Comment: @MueezSiraj There might be many causes, check https://bluepearlvet.com/pet-blog/kitten-diarrhea/ for some explanation. As you can see, it might be lactose, adjustment to a new diet, or simply stress from losing mother and litter mates. Parasites or infectious disease might also be responsible. If there are no qualified vets, it might be an idea to reach out to local shelter or rescue organizations, they sometimes have people with experience taking care of young kittens. Emergency care until then should be keeping him hydrated, and some form of nutrition. Canned food water mix for example.

Comment: I write this with heavy heart. Inspite of trying my best to keep it hydrated and feed sufficiently and not let it starve like its littermates, the fighter gave up n left peacefully in sleep. Probably it was feeling loneliness n stress of the loss of its family. I can't control myself and curse those who fed my minni poison which eventually resulted in 4 deaths in a week. To lift the lifeless bodies of those with whom I played with is so devastating and beyond explanation.

Comment: I am sad to hear this, my condolenced :(